# Estoy realizando un sistema en php y me salta este problema de codigo

Tags: php, laravel

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('
>   in 95fa8dfb635d690d28edcc5a99f8d587929a8d61.php

La ruta que sale manteniendo click por el es

> C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views (line 33)

y esta es la linea que me redirige el enlace (esta es la linea 33  ) :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Categoria</label>
                <select name="idcategoria" class="form-control">
                    <?php $__currentLoopData = $categoria; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as cat): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo e($cat->idcategoria); ?>"><?php echo e($cat->nombre); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: En ese trozo de código hay muchas variables. Alguna de ellas está mandando una sintaxis equivocada.

Comment: Lo que deberías agregar es el código de Blade de dicha vista, esto no es más que una vista compilada de Blade, lo cual ha confundido a las dos personas que pusieron respuestas, quienes al parecer no conocen Laravel.

Comment: @Shaz el error aparece en el fichero compilado, pero no está claro si el código erróneo que aporta esta en éste. Puede estar en su fichero original, que puede usar PHP sin más. El error de sintaxis salta en el compilado que es el que se va a ejecutar.

Comment: @Orici conozco Laravel y Blade lo suficiente para afirmar lo que dije. A lo que voy es a que las dos respuestas sugieren indentar y arreglar el código, como si fuera el OP quien lo hubiera escrito tal cual. Por cierto, daré un +1 a la tuya, que me parece mucho más coherente que la otra, donde incluso se sugiere usar echos en vez de HTML (?).

Answer (score 3):

Indentando un poco tu código (y convirtiendo todo en PHP en vez de interpolar HTML) tienes

```
echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo '<label>Categoria</label>';
echo '<select name="idcategoria" class="form-control">';

$__currentLoopData = $categoria; 
$__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); 

foreach($__currentLoopData as cat): 
   $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); 
   $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); 

   echo '<option value="'. e($cat->idcategoria) .'">'.e($cat->nombre).'</option>';

endforeach; 

$__env->popLoop(); 
$loop = $__env->getLastLoop();

echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
```

ahí se ve un poco más claro que

```
 foreach($__currentLoopData as cat):
```

está mal escrito. Debiera ser

```
 foreach($__currentLoopData as $cat):
```

No tenía idea que Laravel tenía esa función global de conveniencia `e` para escapar entidades html. Otra magia de Laravel. Odio las magias de Laravel.

Comment: Porque es mejor convertirlo en php que interpolar html y php ???

Comment: En este caso donde se usa Blade como template engine no es lo mejor

Comment: @AlbertoMier sólo lo convertí para darle más claridad. La continua apertura y cierre de `<?PHP ?>` hacía menos evidente el problema. Pero una vez solucionado el tema de `cat` puedes devolverlo a la forma que más te acomode.

Answer (score 1):

Mejora el formato de tu código para localizar esos errores fácilmente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Categoria</label>
    <select name="idcategoria" class="form-control">

        <?php 
            $__env->addLoop( $categoria ); 

            foreach ( $categoria as $cat ) {
                $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); 
                $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo e( $cat->idcategoria ); ?>">
            <?php echo e( $cat->nombre ); ?>
        </option>

        <?php 
            } //endforeach

            $__env->popLoop(); 
            $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); 

        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Tenías un error en la declaración del *foreach*: `foreach($__currentLoopData as $cat)`, a **$cat** le faltaba el signo **$** que va al inicio de todas las variables PHP.

Por lo demás, cambie el *foreach* a el formato tradicional que me resulta más legible.

Comment: ¿Es esto una respuesta a la pregunta de OP? Si solo se trata de una edición del código, por favor, usa el enlace [edit]

Comment: @Muriano formatee el código e hice algunas modificaciones.

Comment: Pero no le estás diciendo al usuario dónde tiene su error (aunque tu código sí funciona y copy-pasteándolo el usuario solucionaría el error), por lo que nunca sabría qué hizo mal

Comment: @amenadiel te lo ha explicado. Si no le indicas al usuario qué hizo mal, posiblemente no se dé cuenta de su error. No es eso lo que buscamos. Por favor, tratar de extender un poco más tu respuesta.

Comment: Añadí explicación  de la corrección en el código.